# mysql query to count how many times the like operator matches every column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql ="SELECT * 
       FROM members m 
       INNER JOIN author_details a 
          on m.email= a.email 
       where m.name like '".$search_text."%' 
          or a.username like '".$search_text."%' 
          or a.address_line1 like '%".$search_text."%' 
          or a.address_line2 like '%".$search_text."%' 
          or a.city like '%".$search_text."%' 
          or m.phone = ".(int)$search_text."
```

so what i am looking for is count which column has highest matches and then return that result set first for example if the keyword is found most matches in address column then result set should contain the address matched results first right now the results are displayed for name first even if they are very few.

i am kind of less known to sql so please try to keep it simple

Comment: Try to include some data sample and desire output.

Answer (score 1):

A comparison operator returns `1` when it matches, so you can use `SUM()` to add them up.

```
$sql ="SELECT
            SUM(m.name like '".$search_text."%') AS name_matches,
            SUM(a.username like '".$search_text."%') AS username_matches,
            SUM(a.address_line1 like '%".$search_text."%') AS addr1_matches,
            SUM(a.address_line2 like '%".$search_text."%') AS addr2_matches,
            SUM(a.city like '%".$search_text."%') AS city_matches,
            SUM(m.phone = ".(int)$search_text.") AS phone_matches
       FROM members m 
       INNER JOIN author_details a 
          on m.email= a.email";
```

Each of the `_matches` columns will contain the number of rows where the search text matches in that column.

Comment: I think your answer is great, but OP also want some kind of ordering. But that part isnt easy to do.

Comment: I wasn't really sure what he meant by that, I'm hoping this answer will give him the beginning of the full solution.